# Programmatically modify cells in a filtered datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

If I load up a DataGridView from a datasource,

```
this.exampleTableAdapter.Fill(this.refdataDataSet.Example);
```

Apply a filter via the Binding Source

```
exampleBindingSource.Filter = "TrackingId = 'x'";
```

And then attempt to iterate over the filtered DataGridView and modify them

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridExampleList.Rows)
{
   //Tried to set rows directly
   row.Cells["TrackingId"].Value = "";
   //Also tried variations of setting the DataBoundItem directly
}
```

However, it will not iterate over the entire collection for some reason.

When I debug I get the Rows collection returned (filtered with x items matching the filter), but as I change the values in the collection (specifically the values that are the target of the filter) the collection changes on the fly and the iteration misses items even when the filter is suspended and list change events have been set to false.

Nothing seems to work..

Any suggestions ?

Comment: After setting filtering criterion DataView will hide those rows which do not satisfy the criterion and they become invisible for iteration. But If you need to iterate through all rows anyway then you can set Filter property to null prior to iteration and then restore it after completing the iteration. But you say that you are iterating through the rows of your DataGridView. Please provide your code so we could reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks Bahrom (lord of the rings ?) - I added further info to my question, I have essentially created a minimal project and can reproduce the (reluctant to say error) issue numerous times under various circumstances. Basically, Winforms, any data source, drag a datagridview onto the surface, one button to filter the data to whatever you please and another button to reset the filtered items back <- Thius is where the problem is.. Iterate and change the data.. Voila ... not all rows can be altered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code must let you change all rows.

```
            var filter = exampleBindingSource.Filter;
            exampleBindingSource.Filter = null;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridExampleList.Rows)
            {
                //Tried to set rows directly
                row.Cells["TrackingId"].Value = "";
                //Also tried variations of setting the DataBoundItem directly
            }
            exampleBindingSource.Filter = filter;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the row enumerator, you can try for loop instead:

```
int c = datagridExampleList.Columns["TrackingId"].Index;

for (int r = datagridExampleList.RowCount - 1; r >= 0; r--)
    datagridExampleList[c, r].Value = "";
```